# Date 30 days+ from date in another field

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat, pdf-form

I want to populate a date that is at least 30 days from the date in another field. The field is still editable and should allow for the user to increase the date, just not use any date less than 30 days from the date in another field. Here is what I have so far. It populates the date as 30 days ahead, but I can't increase it.

```
var date= util.scand("mm/dd/yy", this.getField("CurrentDate").value);
date.setDate(date.getDate()+30)
event.value=util.printd("mm/dd/yy",date)
```

Comment: try this this.getField("fieldName").readonly = false;

Answer (score 0):

You can always add any amount of days to a date by converting it to milliseconds and then adding `days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` to it.

See the example below:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
const days = 30;
console.log(addDays(date, days));

function addDays(date, days) {
  return new Date(date.getTime() + days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}
```